# type arguments [W] do not conform to trait type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

```
trait SomeClass {
    ...
}

trait AnotherClass[+V <: SomeClass] {
    ...
}

trait SomeAnotherClass[+V <: SomeClass] {
     protected def someFunc[W >: V](anotherClass: AnotherClass[W]) = {
          ...
     }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
type arguments [W] do not conform to trait AnotherClass's type parameter bounds [+V <: SomeClass]
[error]   protected def someFunc[W >: V](anotherClass: AnotherClass[W]) = ...
[error]                                                    ^
[error] one error found
```

I don't get error when I do `[W >: V <: SomeClass]` instead of just `[W >: V]` , but in this case, it is shadowing the variable. Please help, how to resolve this.

**UPDATE:**

```
protected def someFunc(anotherClass: AnotherClass[V]) = {
              ...
}
```

I get error `covariant type V occurs in contravariant position in type`

Answer (score 2):

When you say `W >: V`, you're saying that the type parameter `W` of `someFunc` must have a lower type bound of `V`. That means that `W` can be `V` or any super-type of it, which would break the type bounds that `V <: SomeClass`.

For example `Any >: SomeClass`, so `W` in this hypothetical situation could be `Any`, but `Any = V <: SomeClass` is not also not true, so the type bounds break.

When you say `W >: V <: SomeClass`, then `W` has a *lower bound of `V`* and an *upper bound of `SomeClass`*. The upper bound of `SomeClass` for `W` is important, because the contained type of `AnotherClass` also has an upper bound of `SomeClass`. Without that, it would try to allow `AnotherClass[Any]` (or some other super-type that isn't `SomeClass`), which of course it can't.

How can you solve this? You have you pick one way to do it. You can't have `W >: V` and `AnotherClass[+V <: SomeClass]` at the same time. It just won't work, because the type bounds conflict.

Comment: You said accepting AnotherClass[V] should be fine. but, `protected def someFunc(anotherClass: AnotherClass[V])` gives error `covariant type V occurs in contravariant position in type AnotherClass`

Comment: I fixed my answer here to explain why it works for `W >: V <: SomeClass`, my earlier comment was mistaken. Why you want it unbounded from above, I don't know.