# type arguments do not conform to trait Bar's type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar[+V <: Foo]
defined trait Bar

scala> trait Baz[+V <: Foo] {
     |    def print[W >: V](bar: Bar[W]) = println("hello bar")
     | }
<console>:10: error: type arguments [W] do not conform to trait Bar's type parameter bounds [+V <: Foo]
          def print[W >: V](bar: Bar[W]) = println("hello bar")

scala> trait Baz[+V <: Foo] {
     |    def print[W >: V <: Foo](bar: Bar[W]) = println("hello bar")
     | }
defined trait Baz
```

Can anybody explain why `[W >: V]` is not working? And how to make it work? And why last case is working.

Comment: How is this different from your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383284/type-arguments-w-do-not-conform-to-trait-type-parameter-bounds)?

Comment: Anish, did that answer clear things up for you?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `Bar` constrains `V` to be `Foo` or a subtype of it.  `W` is constrained to be `V` or a *supertype* of it.  Well, there are some supertypes of `V` which are higher up the inheritance hierarchy than `Foo`, and for those types the constraint `Bar` imposes on `V` is not met.

We can show this graphically by depicting the inheritance hierarchy from left to right:

```
Any, AnyRef, Foo, SomeFooSubType, ...
             V    V                V, ...  (V could be any of these)
                  ^  (let's say it's this one, to illustrate)
W,   W,      W,   W  (then W could be any of these)
^    ^   (but these two violate the constraint that Bar imposes)
```

Perhaps in another question you could say what you are trying to do and ask how to do it?